# How to add thickness symmetrically using the Solidify modifier

Tags: mesh, modifiers

I have a mesh surface which I'd like to add some thickness to using the Solidify modifier, however, it only adds thickness to one side.

I've tried setting the mode to "Complex" but I can't find a way to add an even amount of thickness on both sides.

I also tried adding a second Solid modifier and flipped normals, but this didn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the modifier options there's offset that can be ±1 or 0. The first two add thickness either outside or inside. Setting this to zero gives the result you want. Still, you must remember in this case you add **half** the value to either side.

Comment: I knew I was missing something simple. Thanks a million!